# How I can send POST request

Tags: python, http, django-rest-framework, postman

How can I accept a POST request? I send the request itself through Postman, or maybe I didn't understand correctly and I'm going to the wrong steppe, but the essence of the task is this.
I wrote an endpoint (POST) on DRF, then I will need to make a POST request to this endpoint, and map the data, I would also be grateful if you tell me where to go to make the correct mapping. After the mapping is done, you will need to send this data to another endpoint But I still can’t solve the issue of accepting data on a post request. How can I do this?

As I said I got two endpoints the first one is where, I will make POST request by POSTMAN ->
path ('api/v1/lead',CreateLeadAPI.as_view())
And when I make a post request in POSTMAN I want that, Python could take JSON information make data mapping and send mapped data to the another endpoint

```
class CreateLeadAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = LeadId.objects.all()
    serializer_class = APISerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for translating and thanks for removing the picture of text. You should however show your work, ideally as a [mre] in text form. I keep the close vote, just consider it now "Needs debugging details."

Comment: First, you should start a django server: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver

Answer (score 0):

You can use different framework like Django, Flask, Fast API.

But you need a simple app you can use a http.server:

```
import argparse
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

    def _html(self, message):
        """This just generates an HTML document that includes `message`
        in the body. Override, or re-write this do do more interesting stuff.
        """
        content = f"<html><body><h1>{message}</h1></body></html>"
        return content.encode("utf8")  # NOTE: must return a bytes object!

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self._html("hi!"))

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        # Doesn't do anything with posted data
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(self._html("POST!"))


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, addr="localhost", port=8000):
    server_address = (addr, port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)

    print(f"Starting httpd server on {addr}:{port}")
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a simple HTTP server")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l",
        "--listen",
        default="localhost",
        help="Specify the IP address on which the server listens",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-p",
        "--port",
        type=int,
        default=8000,
        help="Specify the port on which the server listens",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(addr=args.listen, port=args.port)
```